# GZip on IIS6.0 - Some sites work, others don't?

Tags: iis, gzip, metabase

I have a 2k3 server setup running iis6.0 and I've just enabled gzip compression successfully - for the most part. Most sites (eg: clickhips.co.uk) are coming up in YSlow as being compressed fine however the site I'm currently developing (http://www.clickcommercial.co.uk -- DEMO SITE--) is coming up as not compressed.

I've tried adding all the filetypes to the `metabase.xml` file but to no avail.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

OOOops, nevermind - brain-fart the site was hosted on a secondary server so changes werent being migrated for upto 15 minutes :D